# No puedo verificar contraseña para el login

Tags: php

Tengo un login de manera PROCEDIMENTAL pero lo quiero pasar a la forma POO al hacerlo parece que la consulta esta funcionando pero al momento de verificar el login no me funciona, estoy utilizando  password_hash para encriptar las contraseñas y las estoy verificando con PASSWORD_VERYFY he creado muchos usuarios pero no me deja ingresar

```
if (isset($_POST['btnlogin'])) {

//CREAR VALUES PARA INSERTAR
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

//HACEMOS Y PREPARAMOS EL QUERY
$query = "SELECT usuario, contrasena FROM users WHERE usuario = ?";
$stmt = $bd->prepare($query);

//ASOCIAMOS LAS VARIABLES CON EL QUERY
$stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario);

//EJECUTAMOS LA SENTENCIA
$stmt->execute();

//VINCULAMOS DATOS DEBUELTOS A VARIABLES
$stmt->bind_result($v_usuario, $v_contrasena);


//REVISAMOS LA CANTIDAD DE RESUTADOS QUE TENEMOS
$fila = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Hasta aqui parese que funciona si imprimo el usuario que me debuelve la sentencia me sale el mismo que puse y eso ps esta bn pero en esta parte esta lo que no me funciona

```
if (($fila == 1)&&(password_verify($contrasena,$v_contrasena))) {
    $_SESSION['ver_login'] = $usuario;
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}else {
    echo "no funciono";
}
```

No se porque no me funciona ya que pongo la misma contraseña que puse al registrar el usuario

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por que haces un `$fila == 1` si nunca deberia devolverte más de una fila ??

Comment: es para verificar de que no allá otro usuario con el mismo nombre de usuario, es solo de prevención

Comment: Es que, según esa consulta NO DEBE haber alguien con el mismo nombre de usuario, sino entonces, que estás usando de PK ??

Comment: Como haci PK?? contraseña??

Comment: En tu base de datos, PK es clave primaria, unica y no se debe repetir, cual es tu PK en tu base de datos ???

Answer (score 2):

Ok esto no es respuesta, pero es para aclarar la lógica del OP.

Tu base de datos debe tener una columna de dato único, lo que es clave primaria (PK = Primary Key), no se puede ni debe repetirse jamás.

Ahora, la consulta hecha, sin tener una PK, es ambigua. Que quiere decir esto?, es que puede traer más de un resultado.

```
SELECT usuario, contrasena FROM users WHERE usuario = ?
```

Si existen 2 usuarios o más con el mismo usuario, la consulta traerá a todos.
Y no es lo que quieres que pase.

Al momento de traer más de 1 usuario del mismo `usuario`, se produce lo siguiente:

```
// $fila = 2; *ejemplo*
// Comprobamos, fila no es igual a 1, no entramos al IF
if (($fila == 1)&&(password_verify($contrasena,$v_contrasena))) {
    $_SESSION['ver_login'] = $usuario;
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}else{
    //Como no entramos al IF, entramos al ELSE, echo "no funciono";
    echo "no funciono";
}
```

Y asi es como la mala logica arruina tu programacion.
Debes corregir el tema de como identificar al usuario unico.

Comment: OK ya entendi gracias, no lo voy a poner como respuesta porlo que no me responde, pero igualmente muchas gracias

Comment: No lo marques como respuesta, por que no lo es. Lo que debes hacer tu, es corregir tus errores, y si tienes problemas, venir a preguntar acá.